# How to separate an object datatype from a column into multiple columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, python-3.7, data-analysis

My Input is like

"OAM IP:  2001:0506:441c:0710:0000:0011:0814:0002"

which is in a single column, I want to separate it in two column where in the 1st column it contains "OAM IP" which will be always constant and in the 2nd column it will  be 2001:0506:441c:0710:0000:0011:0814:0002 which will change.
I am not able to separate it as it is not a string.

How to write the function with OAM IP in one column ant the numbers into others?

Thanks in advance !

```
infile = (r"C://Users/emonbud/Desktop/Automation/OML02669_PreCheck_08032020_0411.json")
important = []
with open(infile) as f:
    f = f.readlines()

for line in f:
    for phrase in keep_phrases:
        if phrase in line:
            important.append(line)
            break

#print(important)
#s=important
#listToStr = ' '.join(map(str, s))   
#print(listToStr)

df = pd.DataFrame(important)
df.to_csv('C://Users/emonbud/Desktop/Automation/aaroha.csv', index=False, header=False)
df.drop_duplicates()
df.head()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jawe7.png)

Please have a look on this image for better understanding.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7OYR.png)

Comment: You can easily separate the string at the first ':' but, I don't see how you can convert the remining string to a non-string unless you want to convert to a binary or hex sequence.

Comment: As mentioned in a previous comment, this “ How to write the function with OAM IP in one column ant the numbers into others?” is not possible as this is *not* a numeric field due to the colons.  Therefore unless you want a binary encoding (as previously mentioned) this must be a string field.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, thanks